# ContextNotActiveException in simple Faces Flow with CDI

Tags: java, cdi, faces-flow, flow-scope

Hy all !

I'm on a simple faces flow tutorial ([Tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jsf/faces-flow-tutorial)) but can't solve following error:

```
20:43:32,085 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-14) Error Rendering View[/common/signup/signup.xhtml]: javax.el.ELException: /common/signup/signup.xhtml @17,53 value="#{signup.name}": org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1864) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1857) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1860) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.renderAll(PartialViewContextImpl.java:458) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:316) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1857) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:435) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    Caused by: javax.el.ELException: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:368) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
... 52 more
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts   for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:680) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:79) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:78) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
at common.signup.Signup$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getName(Unknown Source) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
... 60 more
```

I'm using Wildfly 8.1.0 as Server. Is there any further serverside configuration necessary for FacesFlow/CDI? (After I did some research ... no, in my opinion.)

**Signup.java**

```
@Named
@FlowScoped(value = "signup")
public class Signup implements Serializable {

private boolean licenseAccepted;
private String name;
private String surname;
private String email;
...
```

**signup-flow.xml**

```
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

<flow-definition id="signup">
    <flow-return id="index">
        <from-outcome>#{signup.homeAction}</from-outcome>
    </flow-return>
</flow-definition>
```

By the way - My pages with RequestScoped backing and friends running perfect, only FlowScoped beans resulting in above posted error.

Hope somebody can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

First I don't know yet the reason but I do know it's related with CDI and **`@Named`** annotation. Just change it to **`javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`** and named it. It's important to import the correct annotation so I write the complete package name:

```
@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean(name = "signIn")
@javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped("signIn")
public class SignInBean implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private boolean licenseAccepted;
  private String name;
  private String surname;
  .....
}
```

Keep the same .xml file

Apart from that notice that other beans can keep the `@Named` annotation. I mean, if you have a `@ViewScope` is possible to keep it as `@Named`instead of `@ManagedBean`.

```
@Named("home")
@javax.faces.view.ViewScoped
public class HomeBean implements Serializable {
   ...
}
```